# not able to pass a array as prop to react component and render it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Problem : I want to pass a array to QuizResult component and need to display it in

tag.

Code:

```
markedAnswers = [0,1,2,3,1,1,4,4]
<QuizResult result={markedAnswers}/>
```

```
const QuizResult = (result) => {
  return (
    <div className="result-screen">

      {result.map((data, index) => <p key={index}> {data}</p>)} - result.map is not a function error

      <div>{result}</div>  - no error, empty div is shown

    </div>
  );
};

export default QuizResult;
```

What i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case:

```
const QuizResult = (result) => {
```

The `result` variable is an object containing all of the passed props.  So you'd refer to `result.result` for the array.  Instead, destructure the props in the function:

```
const QuizResult = ({result}) => {
```

Then `result` would contain just the array.